# Hadoop DistributedCache failed to report status

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

In a Hadoop job i am mapping several XML-files and filtering an ID for every element `(from < id>-tags)`. Since I want to restrict the job to a certain set of IDs, I read in a large file (about 250 million lines in 2.7 GB, every line with just an integer as a ID). So I use a DistributedCache, parse the file in the `setup()` method of the Mapper with a BufferedReader and save the IDs to a HashSet.

Now when I start the job, I get countless

`Task attempt_201201112322_0110_m_000000_1 failed to report status. Killing!`

Before any map-job is executed.

The cluster consists of 40 nodes and since the files of a `DistributedCache` are copied to the slave nodes before any tasks for the job are executed, i assume the failure is caused by the large `HashSet`. I have already increased the `mapred.task.timeout` to 2000s. Of course I could raise the time even more, but actually this period should suffice, shouldn't it?

Since `DistributedCache's` are used to be a way to "distribute large, read-only files efficiently", I wondered what causes the failure here and if there is another way to pass the relevant IDs to every map-job?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some some debug printlns to your setup method to check that it is timing out in this method (log the entry and exit times)?

You may also want to look into using a BloomFilter to hold the IDs in. You can probably store these values in a 50MB bloom filter with a good false positive rate (~0.5%), and then run a secondary job to perform a partitioned check against the actual reference file.